# python 3.9 UnicodeDecodeError:TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: python, file, file-io

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte Oxef in position 3: invalid continuation byte

When I added encoding="utf-8" to my code it got an error:**`File "<string>", line 16, in <module> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`**

I have a list with text files inside when I change the text inside with python it shows this error how can I fix it?

**I am using python version 3.9 and
I use the Fileinput module**

Here is my code:

```
import fileinput
import os
import sys
FILENAME= []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'.' , topdown = False):
    for filename in files:
        if (filename.endswith('.xml')):
            FILENAME.append(filename)
            print(filename)
codeskin = input('Enter Code:')
Prefab = 'prefab_skill_effects/hero_skill_effects/'
codeskinmod = 'prefab_skill_effects/hero_skill_effects/'
Word = Prefab + codeskin
CarNew = input('Enter the Character To Replace:')
CarNews = codeskinmod + CarNew
with fileinput.FileInput(FILENAME , inplace = True ,backup = '.bak' , encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(Word, CarNews), end='')
file.close ()
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the first error as properly formatted text in the question. Ensure that the code is also the first variant.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation for the `fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html), you can see that the `encoding` keyword was added to the constructor on Python 3.10:

> Changed in version 3.10: The keyword-only parameter encoding and errors are added.

If you want to remain using Python 3.9, I believe there is a workaround stated in the docs using the `hookencoded(...)` function. It should look something like this:

```
import fileinput
import os
import sys
FILENAME= []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'.' , topdown = False):
    for filename in files:
        if (filename.endswith('.xml')):
            FILENAME.append(filename)
            print(filename)
codeskin = input('Enter Code:')
Prefab = 'prefab_skill_effects/hero_skill_effects/'
codeskinmod = 'prefab_skill_effects/hero_skill_effects/'
Word = Prefab + codeskin
CarNew = input('Enter the Character To Replace:')
CarNews = codeskinmod + CarNew
with fileinput.FileInput(FILENAME , inplace = True ,backup = '.bak' ,
                         openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8")) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(Word, CarNews), end='')
file.close ()
```

I could not try it myself, since I don't have your file structure. Feel free to play around with it and check the docs I linked above.

Comment: It didn't work but thank you for answering my question